# àèìòù in Android->PHP->Oracle

Tags: php, android, oracle, character-encoding

Android App that have a string `papà` (if I output it, i see: `papà`).

I send this string to a PHP script encoded as JSON and if I echo this string I read: `pap�`.

If I see in the database it stored as `pap�` (obviously).

If I write `papà` direclty in the database I read `papà` (obviously).

At this point I'm near sure that the problem is PHP, I tried with `htmlentities` and in the database I read `pap&agrave`.

I think you have all information for my problem. Any idea?

Edit to add code:

In Android I have string put in a map:

```
dati.put("tipo", sottoT);
```

after do the params for Json

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : dati.entrySet()) {
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL,
            "POST", params);
```

I send the Json:

```
 public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

In PHP I take the data from POST:

```
header('Content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8');
$array = array();
foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v) {
    $array[$k] = $v;
}
```

`$v` at this point is already wrong...

PHP Version 5.3.14

Comment: For the `htmlentities` try you did, please add the code how you tried that. Also please share the exact PHP version you're using. Also please post the JSON string you get from the Android Application. How do you process that JSON string in PHP? Please show that code as well.

Comment: If `$v`  at that point is already wrong, check the character encoding the POST request comes with. You need to know that. It looks like it is not UTF-8 - but you treat it like. Maybe Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1?

Comment: i wrote how i did the post in android..

Comment: Your Android code tells nothing about the character encoding. Which character encoding are you using for the data processed by that Android code? Please add that to your question. Your PHP version and the (not shown) `htmlentities` example make me assume that the character encoding is  ISO-8859-1. Use that instead of UTF-8 when you process the data in PHP. E.g. does `var_dump(utf8_encode($v));`show the correct characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for your curiosity... i finally fix the problem. I miss to add th charset the db have to use so i put:
`$conn = oci_new_connect($userDb, $pswDB, $urlDb, 'AL32UTF8');`
instead
`$conn = oci_new_connect($userDb, $pswDB, $urlDb);`

So Android have:
`httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "utf-8"));`
In Php i have:
`header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` (don't know if this is important)

This is all..ty all for help

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the encoding in the android code:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
```

Otherwise it will be [ISO-8859-1](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/protocol/HTTP.html#DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET).

On the PHP side, **do not** do any conversion such as `utf8_decode/encode`, these will always just make it worse.

Also fix your http header:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: The constructor UrlEncodedFormEntity(List<NameValuePair>, Charset) is undefined

Comment: @Atomico ok, how about `new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8")` ? Should work according to android docs http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html

Comment: @Atomico ok so that's working then, how are you viewing the result?

Comment: `pap��` ... i am going crazy

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to transform it into html sign? Like `$#numbers;`. If not than state encoding like `utf-8 general_ci` or `ANSI`. it helped me once.

Comment: can you explain better pls

Comment: Well for typing code I use PHP Designer 7, but when I need to change encoding of the code, I use `notepad++`. It has functions like `Encode in UTF-8` of `Encode in ANSI`. Also you can google all special letters and encode them according to the next exapmle:
space is coded as &#32;
à is coded as &#224;
You can find all of them there:
http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm